# Многострочный ввод

Tags: cmd, bat

Мне нужно в bat файле передать на StdIn сторонней программы многострочную строку. Это можно как-то сделать без промежуточного файла?

Пробовал так

```
set line=a^
b^
c
echo %line% | myprog.exe
```

но программа получает склеенную строку `abc` а хотелось получить многострочную

```
a
b
c
```

Пока вариант

```
echo a>file.tmp
echo b>>file.tmp
echo c>>file.tmp
myprog.exe < file.tmp
```

не рассматривается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(echo a & echo b & echo c) | myprog.exe
```

Comment: А если итоговую строку кроме направления на stdin нужно вывести на экран?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, https://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/4928642

Comment: Круто! Теперь бы разобраться как оно работает. Спасибо

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, там на эту тему ссылка отдельный вопрос в комментах: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6379619/4928642